# Errors when compiling AKKA code under 2.7.7

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am a very new bie for scala. So I download the source code AKKA and install the plugin for eclipse (2.7.7 final). When I open the project, it shows 29 compile errors. I know it may be version mismatch or plugin setting issue. But I don't know how to trouble shoot it.

**a) ')' expected but '=' found.**:

```
case class HotSwap(code: ActorRef ⇒ Actor.Receive, discardOld: Boolean = true)
```

**b) identifier expected but 'object' found.**

```
package object actor
```

Can anyone help this simple question?

Thanks a lot:)

**UPDATE:**

A similiar question is asked by **jilen**.

[How to add sbteclipse plugin to SBT 0.10.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566470/how-to-add-sbteclipse-pluging-to-sbt-0-10-x)

Comment: @x3ro I knew nothing about the latest version of scala when I downloaded the code.Actually now I turn to SBT tool. Perhaps the guys who develop AKKA only use SBT and don't use the eclipse at all.

Comment: Actually SBT eclipse 0.10 seems to only support Scala 2.8.1 which makes me a bit lost. Maybe I was wrong. Anyone has update?           https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/blob/master/README.textile

Comment: I recently used the latest version of Akka with Scala 2.9.0RC2 and it worked just fine (with eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default parameters do not exist in Scala 2.7.

You can fake them (sometimes sanely) though:

```
// Note no "= true" which specified the default value
case class HotSwap(code: Any, discardOld: Boolean)
object HotSwap {
  def apply(code: Any): HotSwap = HotSwap(code, true)
}    
>> defined class HotSwap
>> defined module HotSwap    
HotSwap("x")    
>> res1: HotSwap = HotSwap(x,true)    
HotSwap("x",false)    
>> res2: HotSwap = HotSwap(x,false)
```

The second set of errors is because [Package Objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html#) were also introduced in Scala 2.8. I have never dealt with them, though. "Fixing" this likely requires a good bit more work on updating references, but see previous.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

The newest akka version builds only with scala 2.9. Is it possibly for you to use this version? It would save you a lot of trouble.